# How to set size for divs with different parents

Tags: css, html

I want to create a div layout which is similiar to the following table result:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic</title>
        <style>
            table { border: 1px solid;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table style="border: 1px solid;">
        <tr>
            <td> Asia</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>South Asia</td>
                        </td>
                        <td><table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Republic</td>
                                    <td><table>
                                            <tr><td>Singapore</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>India</td></tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Monarchy</td>
                                    <td><table>
                                            <tr><td>Bhutan</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Nepal</td></tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                        </table></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>East Asia</td>
                        <td><table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Republic</td>
                                    <td><table>
                                            <tr><td>China</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>South Corea</td></tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Constitutional Monarchy</td>
                                    <td><table>
                                            <tr><td>something</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Japan</td></tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I managed to replicate this with some effort. The problem is that I want the names of the countries to be in a column or if you will - the containers for the government types to be the same width so other containers will align.

If I don't do it in nested containers (in the example - nested tables) the rows will get displaced. Currently rows are shown exactly how I want them - the text is in the vertical middle of the what they refer to.

Only thing that comes up to my mind is to set the text in the same columns as class=column1, class=column2, etc. and then somehow define the width for the column classes. Problem is the data is defined dynamically and I can't say how much pixels or % of the page I can give to a column, I just need it to stretch with the text.

This is my first time I ask about help here so if I am doing it wrong, tell me how do improve my inquiry.

EDIT: I just read it a second time and I noticed my title doesn't match my question.
My second idea to work around this was to have more than one parent to a single div without the parents having a relation between them, is this even possible?

Comment: Good grief.. a table inside a table inside a table inside a table. You should take a look at rowspan or something

Comment: thanks for the great tip, man. The table looks exactly how I want it. All that is left now is to figure out the equivalent of rowspan in css divs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a decent grid framework for your CSS, I highly recommend [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/).  As for not knowing the pixel or % for the column, that will always be a problem.  Are you able to 'play it safe' and just give them a large enough box to handle all text possibilities?

Comment: I could make a php script to assign them a class related to the data type and then this class will be in CSS with a set size. I don't like it much cause even the same type of data could be very different sizes